# how can I use Prometheus counters and metrics in OwinStartup.cs in dot-net framework 4.6.1

Tags: .net, frameworks, prometheus, performancecounter

I really need to find a sample code with counters for all methods in controllers.
I have used the following code but none of my counters are available on the Prometheus (Localhost:9090)

```
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UsePrometheusServer(q =>
            {
                q.MapPath = "/api/metrics";
            });
            var counter = Metrics.CreateCounter("SampleCounter", "some help about this");
            counter.Inc(5.5);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing "/api/metrics" => "/metrics";
and just used counter.Inc();